# Combine date and time into a valid date time

Tags: javascript

I have the below date and time in an object, i need to merge it and get the actual date with time as like normal new Date();

```
let obj = {
  date: "2021-4-1",
  time: "5:29:59:0"
}
```

How can i merge this two into a single valid date object ?

I have tried [date-fns parseISO](https://date-fns.org/v2.21.1/docs/parseISO) method also but didn't worked. Or in JS itself there is a simpler way.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `new Date(obj.date + " " + obj.time)` ?

Comment: Agree --^ , or else try `new Date(obj.date + " " + obj.time + "Z")` (difference in timezone behavior)

Comment: Why does it show `Invalid Date` for me?

Comment: Not sure, but you may need to add leading zeros to the day and month in the date in order for new Date() to work, due to the way it parses it.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to do this, is probably to use the [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) JS library. You will need to add leading zeros to both the `obj.date` days and months and to `obj.time` hours, but once that is in place using Luxon is easy!

Once imported, you can just use the following code:

```
DateTime.fromISO(obj.date + 'T' + obj.time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 let val = obj.date + obj.time + "Z";
    console.log("Date and time format 1:", new Date(val));

If you still get error, try to convert val into string manually and use new Date(),

    let stringVal = val.toString();
    console.log("Date and time format 2:", new Date(stringVal));
```

Comment: `val` is already a string, why would converting it to a string help?